# Building an android-ndk-r17c standalone toolchain with Cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, toolchain

I would like to import the library [libsndfile](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/). According to it's [doc](https://github.com/erikd/libsndfile/blob/master/Building-for-Android.md) I need a standalone toolchain for this. Now I'm trying to build said toolchain with Cygwin as described in the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain) but get the error message:

```
Unsupported platform: CYGWIN_NT-10.0.
```

I am new to android development and must admit that I struggle with the official guide quite a bit. From what I understand the `--arch` argument refers to the system I'm building for and the `--api` argument to the (minimum?) Android version it is running. Which toolkit exactly it is should be irrelevant at this point as long as they are compatible. So for now let's go with `--arch x86_64` and `--api 21`. Overall the in- and output look as follows:

```
$ ./build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch x86_64 --api 21 -v --install-dir ../toolchains/oboe_record_proto/
Unsupported platform: CYGWIN_NT-10.0
```

Comment: It seems mingw and not cygwin is the preferred installation for NDK.

Comment: The official guide says _"The NDK build system ensures that all paths passed to the compiler from Cygwin are automatically translated, and manages other complexities, as well. If you have a custom build system, you may need to resolve these complexities yourself."_ I'm not sure what "custom build system" means. Can that be the case here?

Comment: Also, would it make sense to install Mingw on top and try that out? It's just that I'm worried that that might mess up some dependencies.

Comment: May be cygwin was supported before but not now. `$ python checkbuild.py
.... RuntimeError: Unsupported host: cygwin`

Comment: added to wrong place: it is a comment, not an answer I posted.  
--arch is for target cpu architecture, i.e., your Android device's cpu type. it could be: arm arm64 x86 x86_64.  this is inside the python file you are running.

Comment: That makes one less misconception on my part. This could have caused truoble running the compiled code on a device later down the line. I will adjust my question accordingly.

Comment: That comment is a little vague. "The NDK build system" refers to ndk-build. Standalone toolchains are not a build system. The comment is intended as a warning that people using standalone toolchains in their build systems will likely need to perform path translation if they want to support being invoked from mingw. I'll fix the doc (probably by just removing that section, since I don't think it's particularly helpful).

Comment: Doc is updated to remove the misleading paragraph. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a satisfying answer but here what worked for me in the end:

According to the comment by matzeri, Cygwin is not supported (anymore). My attempts to solve it with Mingw / Msys as suggested were without success either.
Ths, I installed python under Windows and ran the script from the Windows command line.

```
python .\build\tools\make_standalone_toolchain.py --arch x86_64 --api 21 -v --install-dir ..\toolchains\oboe_record_proto
```

The toolchain was generated as expected.